# Деепричастный оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Допустимо ли здесь обособление деепричастного оборота? Вроде ни под какое исключение не подходит.

Опыт Польши, Эстонии, Чехии, Словакии, Венгрии, Словении показал, что (,) сочетая различные виды производства и имея надежных поставщиков арматуры и оборудования из Восточной Европы и азиатских стран, можно создать надежный и эффективный бизнес.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правы, Аленка, здесь нет никаких исключений для обособления двух однородных обстоятельств, выраженных деепричастными оборотами. Запятые расставлены правильно

Answer (score 0):

Сочетая виды И имея поставщиков арматуры И оборудования из Европы И азиатских стран...

Занятная цепочка...

Comment: Ну тут союз "и" соединяет разные однородные члены. Но на запятые это ведь никак не влияет? Они там не ставятся. Два деепричастных оборота запятыми не разделяются, выступают в роли однородных членов. "арматуры и оборудования" - одна пара однородных членов, "из Европы и азиатских стран" - другая.